# Optimal numerial method for optimization of "Rosenbrock Banana"-like function

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Which numerical methods would be optimal to find an extremum of a function with an almost flat "valley" (but a single minimum in the middle of the valley)? In this context optimal means the least number of function evaluations.

For simplicity's sake, assume that it's a two-dimensional problem.
Also, of importance may be that I am more interested not in the coordinates of the extremum, but the value of the function in it.

For reference, the [Rosenbrock function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function) is 
$$f(x,y) = (1-x)^2 + 100(y-x^2)^2$$

(I am using the term "'Rosenbrock'-like", because I have not yet defined the function itself. The problem I am solving is that of nonlinear equality constraint optimization, which I believe I have reduced to a global optimization of a function with a "valley" along the constraint.)

PS.
This is my firsts question posted on this site, so I apologize, if I have done something incorrectly. Please let me know of that is the case.

Comment: A better (more targeted) site for this question is [scicomp.se]

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY Yeah, I have found that by now, and posted there. Thanks!

Comment: I see you reproduced the typo in the title: "numerial". :) Link to the question at SciComp: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/11807. If you want, you can delete the question here.